# Why is this taking 14k it/s reduction of key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I have a function that reads a file full of json. Each line of json has around 78 key value pairs which i convert using

```
data={key:data.get(key,"") for key in keys}
```

to only key value pairs which I need and then upload to duckdb.

```
def upload(file,conn):
    n=0
    temp=[]
    keys=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10','x11','x12','x13','x14','x15','x16','x17','x18','x19','x20','x21','x22','x23','x24','x25','x26','x27','x28','x29','x30','x31','x32','x33','x34','x35'
]
    for line in tqdm(file):
        data=json.loads(line)
        data={key:data.get(key,"") for key in keys}
        temp.append(data)
    df=pd.DataFrame(temp)
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO Main SELECT * FROM df')
    temp=[]
```

The duckdb part of code is working very fast but the loop is running at around 14000 it/s How can I improve this speed?

Comment: What do you mean by "it/s"? Your loop should be very fast. How many lines are there in the input file? Also, your INSERT won't take into account anything that's in the DataFrame!

Comment: How fast is it without that dict comp line?

Comment: it/s means iterations per second

Comment: Have you tried using pandas and filters?
Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748739/using-pandas-for-json-document-filtering or https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/ref_df_filter.asp

Comment: Your *for* loop iterates over the output of *tqdm()*. It processes a line of text making it a Python dictionary from JSON. It constructs a dictionary containing 35 key/value pairs. For each pair it does a lookup (*get()*) on the input dictionary. It appends that dictionary to a list. It does all of that 14,000 times per second and that's not fast enough for you. If that's the case you might want to consider not using an interpreted language like Python

Comment: @Pingu If the interpretation is what makes it slow, we could get rid of almost all of it. (Just replace the dict comp with something doing it in C.)

Comment: I've done some testing on my machine and tqdm reports >53,000 it/s so it looks like your hardware may be the issue here

Comment: @Pingu How fast is it without that dict comp line? (I.e., I'm curious whether it's the loads or the dict comp that takes most time.)

Comment: @KellyBundy goes to >65,000 it/s

Comment: @Pingu Ok, so it's mostly the loads. Perhaps `dict(zip(keys, map(data.get, keys, itertools.repeat(""))))` would be faster than the dict comp, but that wouldn't even help much then.